# XSS prevention by securing cookies locally

Tags: web-browser, xss, browser-hijacking

i was wondering if there was a way to prevent XSS by creating a safe layer within the storage of cookies in the browser locally? Or would there be any unique ways to protect against XSS. I know this has probably been done before but I am rather new at this so would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: XSS doesn't need cookies, so such efforts would only be partially successful at best.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot prevent XSS by using cookies, but you can prevent successful XSS attacks from stealing your cookies by setting the [HTTP-only](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) flag. HTTP-only cookies are not visible in the context of the javascript engine. This is the only connection I can see between XSS and cookies.

What you should look into instead, is the CSP ([Content Security Policy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Content_Security_Policy)) HTTP-header. It instruct the browser where its allowed to load content and scripts from.

There are many questions and answers regarding CSP that can aid you here.
https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=csp